# TPM and trust in cloud provider

Tags: trust, tpm, trusted-computing

I'm kinda unclear and confused ,i'm searching on the subject of trusted module platform and i can resume the main tpm's functions are: authentication functions, integrity measurement functions and attestation functions.

By trust we mean that the platform will behave as excpected.
Now as a user who has no idea about the behaviour of the cloud provider (eg:amazon e2c) meaning he doesn't trust it. however there is a trusted third party (which the user and the cloud provider trust) going to request measuerements from the cloud provider ,do operations and then respond to user if the cloud is trusted or not?
the TPM now is supposed to be in the cloud part i guess but does it mean every node in the cloud should contain a tpm chip ? and must valid its integrity? then as a user i would trust the cloud provider if all nodes are considered trusted?
thanks

Comment: Do you want a TPM in your cloud? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @vidarlo how the implementation of the tpm in cloud let the client trust this cloud ?

Comment: The TPM would need to be on the underlying host hardware. You can't attest a VM in the same way.

Comment: @forest https://people.mpi-sws.org/~gummadi/papers/trusted_cloud.pdf like in this paper it says that the tpm should be available in the nodes